# $H(G) \cup \{\infty\}$ is closed in $C(G,\mathbb C_{\infty}).$

Tags: complex-analysis, meromorphic-functions

Let $G \subseteq \mathbb C$ be a region and $H(G),M(G)$ and $C(G,\mathbb C_{\infty})$ be respectively denote the spaces of holomorphic functions, meromorphic functions and extended complex valued continuous functions on $G$ respectively. Then in **Theorem 3.4** (Page no. $156$) in Conway's book on complex analysis it has been proved that $M(G) \cup \{\infty\}$ is a complete metric space. As a corollary it has been claimed that $H(G) \cup \{\infty\}$ is a closed subset of $C(G,\mathbb C_{\infty}).$ It is clear to me that $H(G) \cup \{\infty\}$ is contained in the closure of $H(G)$ when considered as a subset of $C(G, \mathbb C_{\infty}).$ But how to prove that there is nothing outside $H(G) \cup \{\infty\}$ in the closure of $H(G)\ $? Is it due to the fact that $H(G) \subseteq M(G)\ $? If so,  how do I show that there won't be any meromorphic function in the closure of $H(G)$ when viewing it as a subset of $C(G,\mathbb C_{\infty})\ $?

Any help in this regard would be warmly appreciated. Thanks for investing your valuable time.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $H(G)$ which converges to $f \in M(G) \cup \{\infty\}$ with respect to the spherical metric. We want to show that $f$ is holomorphic or identically $\infty$.

If $f(z_0) = \infty$ then there is a small neighborhood $V$ of $z_0$ such that $1/f$ and all $1/f_n$ are holomorphic $V$, and $1/f_n \to 1/f$ uniformly in $V$ with respect to the spherical metric. It follows that also $1/f_n \to 1/f$ uniformly with respect to the Euclidean metric.

All $1/f_n$ are non-zero in $V$. [Hurwitz's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) states that $1/f$ is non-zero in $V$ or identically zero in $V$. But $1/f(z_0) = 0$, so $1/f$ is identically zero in $V$.

So we have shown the following: If $f(z_0) = \infty$ then $f(z) = \infty$ in a neighborhood of $V$. Since poles of meromorphic functions are isolated, we have that either $f$ is identically $\infty$, or $f$ has no poles, i.e. $f \in H(G)$.

Comment: Our instructor said that it can be proved as a corollary of **Theorem 3.4**. I can able to prove it independently but don't know how to prove it as a consequence of the preceding theorem. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @AntonioClaire: I do not have that book. But as I understand it, Theorem 3.4 guarantees that a Cauchy sequence of holomorphic functions is convergent in $M(G)\cup \{\infty\}$. It remains to show that the limit function is in $H(G) \cup \{\infty\}$, and that is what I did.

Comment: @AntonioClaire: That the convergence with respect to the spherical metric implies convergence with respect to the Euklidean metric in $V$ is of course a consequence of your recent question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4216954/42969.

Comment: @AntonioClaire: Did you make any progress here?