# Spherical metric restricted to the complex plane is equivalent to the usual Euclidean metric.

Tags: complex-analysis, metric-spaces, equivalent-metrics

> Let $a \in \mathbb C$ and $r \gt 0$ be given; then there exists $\rho \gt 0$ such that $B_{\infty} (a,\rho) \subseteq B(a,r),$ where $$B_{\infty} (a,\rho) = \{z \in \mathbb C\ |\ d_{\infty} (z,a) \lt \rho \}$$

Here $$d_{\infty} (z,z') = \frac {2\ |z-z'|} {{\left [\left (1 + |z|^2 \right ) \left (1 + |a|^2 \right ) \right ]}^{\frac {1} {2}}}$$ if $z,z' \in \mathbb C$ and $$d_{\infty} (z,\infty) = \frac {2} {\left (1 + |z|^2 \right )^{\frac {1} {2}}}$$ if $z \in \mathbb C.$ By choosing $0 \lt \rho \lt \frac {1} {\left (1 + |a|^2 \right )^{\frac {1} {2}}}$ we can guarantee that $\infty \notin B_{\infty} (a,\rho).$ I am trying to show that $|z - z'| \leq C\ d_{\infty} (z,z'),$ for $C \gt 0$ but I didn't able to conclude that. Could anyone please help me in this regard?

Thanks for investing your valuable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a \in \Bbb C$ and $r > 0$. Choose $\rho > 0$ with $0 < \rho < d_\infty(a, \infty)$ and
$$
\frac{2\rho}{(d_\infty(a, \infty) - \rho) d_\infty(a, \infty)} < r \, .
$$

For all $z \in B_{\infty} (a,\rho)$ is
$$ 
d_\infty(z, \infty) \ge d_\infty(a, \infty) - d_\infty(a, z) \ge d_\infty(a, \infty) - \rho > 0
$$
from the triangle inequality for the spherical metric. It follows that
$$
 |z-a| = \frac{2d_\infty(z,a)}{d_\infty(z, \infty) d(a, \infty)}
\le \frac{2\rho}{(d_\infty(a, \infty) - \rho) d_\infty(a, \infty)} < r
$$
and therefore $z \in B(a, r)$.

Comment: From the inequality involving $\rho$ and $r$ we have $$0 \lt \rho \lt \frac {r\ d_{\infty} (a,\infty)} {2 + r\ d_{\infty} (a,\infty)}.$$ Does it imply that $\rho \lt d_{\infty} (a,\infty)\ $? This is needed to ensure that $\infty \notin B_{\infty} (a,\infty).$ Otherwise we need to take $$0 \lt \rho \lt \min \left \{\frac {r\ d_{\infty} (a,\infty)} {2 + r\ d_{\infty} (a,\infty)}, d_{\infty} (a,\infty) \right \}.$$ Isn't it so @Martin R?

Comment: @AntonioClaire: Note that I suggested to choose $\rho$ such that $0 < \rho < d_\infty(a, \infty)$ **and** $\frac{2\rho}{(d_\infty(a, \infty) - \rho) d_\infty(a, \infty)} < r $.

Comment: Oh!  Sorry. I missed that. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @AntonioClaire: Actually the second inequality is satisfied if $0 \lt \rho \lt \frac {r\ d_{\infty} (a,\infty)^2} {2 + r\ d_{\infty} (a,\infty)}$, and that *does* imply $\rho \lt d_{\infty} (a,\infty)$. But I don't find that so important, we only need that $B_{\infty} (a,\rho) \subseteq B(a,r)$ for *some* positive $\rho$.