# Show the Euclidean metric and the metric formed by projection through the Riemann Sphere on $\mathbb{C}$ are equivlent.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces

The function $\phi:\mathbb{C}\to S^2$ given by
$$z\mapsto \frac{\left(2\text{Re}(z),2\text{Im}(z),|z|^2-1\right)}{|z|^2+1}$$
constitute a 'natural' map between the Riemann sphere (sans the north pole) and the complex plane. For more information on this, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4550723/what-function-naturally-maps-the-complex-plane-into-the-unit-sphere?noredirect=1#comment9570914_4550723).

---

How may one show that the metric defined by
$$d:\mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{R}:(z,w)\mapsto |\phi(z)-\phi(w)|$$
is equivalent to the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4216954/42969

Comment: @MartinR I've seen such $d_{\infty}$ metric around, although I do not see why it is equivalent do the metric $d$ I have defined.

Comment: If you expand $|\phi(z)-\phi(w)|$ then you should see that it is exactly that metric (perhaps up to a constant factor).

Comment: @MartinR I've tried. Letting $K_i=|z_i|^2+1$, then
$\| \phi(z_1)-\phi(z_2)\|^2 = \frac{\left[2x_1K_2-2x_2K_1\right]^2+\left[2y_1K_2+2y_2`K_1\right]^2+\left[(|z_1|^4-1)(|z_2|^4-1)\right]^2}{(|z_1|^2+1)^2(|z_2|^2+1)^2} = \frac{4\left[x_1K_2-x_2K_1\right]^2+4\left[y_1K_2-y_2K_1\right]^2+\left[(|z_1|^4-1)(|z_2|^4-1)\right]^2}{K_1^2K_2^2}$

Comment: I am pretty sure that what I said above is correct. Of course you must use that (in your notation) $K_i = x_i^2 + y_i^2 + 1$.

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, the equivalence of the metrics also follows from the fact that both $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$ are *continuous.*

Comment: @MartinR could you further explain why it would follow from $\phi$ and $\phi^{-1}$ being continuous? I know other conditions for metrics to be equivalent, such as the ones found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_of_metrics#Topological_equivalence

Answer (score 1):

You certainly know that two metrics on a set $X$ are equivalent if and only if they induce the same topology on $X$.

Letting $N =(0,0,1)$ denote the north pole of $S^2$ and $S^2_* =  S^2 \setminus \{N\}$, we get a function
$$\phi : \mathbb C\to S^2_*, \phi(z) = \dfrac{(2\operatorname{Re}(z), 2\operatorname{Im}(z), \lvert z \rvert^2 -1)}{ \lvert z \rvert^2 +1} $$
which is obviously continuous. Here $S^2_*$ has the subspace topology inherited from $\mathbb R^3$; it is induced by the Euclidean metric $d_e(a,b) = \lVert a - b \rVert$.

The function $\phi$ is the inverse of the well-known *stereographic projection*
$$p :  S^2_* \to \mathbb C, p(x,y,z) = \dfrac{x+iy}{1-z}.$$
This function is a *homeomorphism*: It is clearly continuous and one easily verifies that $\phi \circ p = id$ and $p \circ \phi = id$ which means that $\phi$ is a continuous inverse of $p$.

The metric $d_c(z,w) = \lVert \phi(z) - \phi(w) \rVert$ is known as the *chordal metric on $\mathbb C$*. Let us denote by $\tilde{\mathbb C}$ the topological space whose topology is induced by $d_c$.  Clearly $\phi : (\mathbb C,d_c) \to (S^2_*,d_e)$ is an isometry, hence $\phi : \tilde{\mathbb C} \to S^2_*$ is a homeomorphism. Thus the composition
$$id = p \circ \phi : \tilde{\mathbb C} \stackrel{\phi}{\to} S^2_* \stackrel{p}{\to} \mathbb C$$
is a homeomorphism which means that $\tilde{\mathbb C} =  \mathbb C$ as topological spaces.